# Unity WebcamTexture advanced settings (exposure, focus, zoom)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I have my camera feed working in Unity that uses WebcamTexture. According to https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.html, there are no features for changing the exposure or focus settings.

Just to be clear:

1. Is there any way to change the exposure of WebcamTexture?
2. If not, is there any other way to adjust the exposure **without** using WebcamTexture?
3. If not, what are some widely used API/tools that I can use in Unity for getting camera feed with these adjustable settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to change the exposure of WebcamTexture?

No. You can on [Android](https://forum.unity.com/threads/webcamtexture-on-android-focus-mode-fix.327956/) with `AndroidJavaObject` but that's a hack and can stop working each time there is Unity update. Also, it will only work on Android but not on iOS, Windows, Mac and other platforms.

> If not, is there any other way to adjust the exposure without using
>   WebcamTexture?

Again, no. You can't modify the camera settings while using `WebcamTexture`.

> If not, what are some widely used API/tools that I can use in Unity
>   for getting camera feed with these adjustable settings?

The only way to be able to modify the camera settings you mentioned is to create a camera API plugin for each platform. This is not easy to do since you have to know many programming languages to get it working such as Java for Android, Objective-C for iOS and Mac, C++ for Windows and Linux and Javascript for WebGL then use C# to put them together. It's really time-consuming to make this and therefore better to use an existing plugin.

The best one out there is the [NatCam](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/natcam-webcam-api-52154) plugin. This plugin can control the exposure, focus and zoom of the camera *but it's not free.* It's worth it.

You can set the exposure and the exposure bias as:

```
DeviceCamera.RearCamera.ExposureMode = ExposureMode.Locked;
NatCam.Camera.ExposureBias = NatCam.Camera.MinExposureBias;
```

To set the Focus Mode:

```
NatCam.Camera.FocusMode = FocusMode.TapToFocus | FocusMode.AutoFocus;
```

To zoom the camera:

```
NatCam.Camera.ZoomRatio = 2.0f;
```

You can find the complete tutorial for NatCam [here](https://medium.com/@olokobayusuf/natcam-tutorial-series-2-controls-d2e2d0738223).

Comment: Thank you! I decided to write a plugin using UWP's MediaFrameReader and use that to render in Unity! I will put you as an answer.

Comment: The UWP's MediaFrameReader  stuff will only work on Windows but that's a good start. You can always add support for other platforms.

Comment: Note the Natcam plugin only lets you control these settings on "native devices" meaning the built in camera on a phone or tablet. You cannot control the exposure of a webcam via this plugin for a USB webcam on a windows platform for instance. I talked to the developers about this and verified you cannot :(